# Math via Skype on a Mac?

Tags: skype, handwriting

I find myself needing to explain math via Skype (to nephews, nieces in high-school or college, etc.) with increasing frequency, enough so that the clumsy approach of holding a pad of paper up to the camera is beginning to get irksome.

*Typing* out the math into the interface's text field, or anywhere else, I find even more irksome.

I would like to communicate the math, in real time, both by voice and by writing, sketching, etc.  Preferably I'd also like to be able to see the person I'm showing the math to.  With Skype I get the real-time voice and image communication.  I just need a way to add a handwritten channel somehow.

Can someone recommend a way to do it on a Mac?

Comment: It depends on your budget! Whiteboard, writepad, skechpad ect....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the screen share?

It does require you typing, but not in the Skype field.

You could use excel or word to type, and then share your screen with others.

More details HOW to:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10022/how-do-i-share-my-screen-in-skype-for-mac-os-x

You will also need a digital sketch pad like the :

http://www.wacom.com/en/products/pen-tablets/bamboo/bamboo-connect#tabpane2

Comment: Sorry, I should have made my dislike for any solution that involves typing more clear.  I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @kjo, no problem, but you still want to use skype ?

Comment: Yes.  I clarified my post a bit more.

Comment: idroo, like pretty much everything I've found, is only for windows...

Comment: Letme back off for a moment!, you want a sketch pad (without OCR) that shows what you writing on your screen. Than using screen-share on Skype you can share it. So all you need to do is to choose which digital pad you want.

Answer (score 3):

### [BaiBoard](http://www.baiboard.com)

BaiBoard is a free white board tool that allows you to share and collaborate on a virtual white board. It allows the use of free hand drawing, typing, lines, etc. There is a free [Mac](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/baiboard/id482322064?ls=1&mt=12) and [iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/baiboard-hd/id490534358?ls=1&mt=8) app. I find it works really well with google talk for audio chatting whilst a Wacom Graphics tablet for input.

Comment: The Mac version of Baiboard is not as capable as the iOS version.